# We using this Asyncimageview classes to get image from web serves and showing in UItableview but is not working?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

```
//UITableView   

 NSString *data_image;

data_image = [[message_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"img_thumb"];

NSLog(@"data_image---%@",data_image);


if (![data_image isEqualToString:@""])
{
    img_bubble = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:cloudImage];
    [img_bubble setFrame:CGRectMake(225, 0,85 , 80)];

    img_buble_sender = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:cloudImage1];

    [img_buble_sender setFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,90,80)];

    urlImage  = [NSURL URLWithString:[[message_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image"]];



    asyncImage = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(238, 10, 55, 55)];
    [asyncImage loadImageFromURL:urlImage];

    //images1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(238, 10,55 , 55)];
    //[images1 setImageWithURL:urlImage];

}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: We using UITableView for chat function but we don't show image on cell  but in iOSSimulator it is show but device or not showing the Image.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        //create new cell
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        //common settings
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(238, 10, 55, 55);
        cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    }
    else {
        //cancel loading previous image for cell
        [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:cell.imageView];
    }

    //set placeholder image or cell won't update when image is loaded
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];

    //load the image
    cell.imageView.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[message_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about which AsyncImageView you are using, but you could try this:

```
//UITableView 
NSString *data_image;

data_image = [[message_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"img_thumb"];

NSLog(@"data_image---%@",data_image);


if (![data_image isEqualToString:@""])
{
    img_bubble = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:cloudImage];
    [img_bubble setFrame:CGRectMake(225, 0,85 , 80)];

    img_buble_sender = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:cloudImage1];

    [img_buble_sender setFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,90,80)];

    urlImage  = [NSURL URLWithString:[[message_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"image"]];

    asyncImage = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(238, 10, 55, 55)];
    [asyncImage loadImageFromURL:urlImage];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:asyncImage];
}
```